# Unable to opening file with ifstream

Tags: c++

I'd like to get some assistance regarding the following line of code.
for the function constructArray,I'm unable to run it as shows the !aFile as true message but I have no idea what's the error.
Really appreciative of your assistance
Also how do I create inFile fileName with .txt,i've tried indentation with +".txt" but due to the file type in the argument i'm unable to do so.
Compiler run image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4orq.jpg

```
    using namespace std;

    enum NumType {Odd, Even};

    struct Number
    {
         int no;
         NumType type;
         int oddDigits;
         int evenDigits;
         int sumDigits;
         int noDigits;
    };

    // Create inFile data file with certain number of integers which are randomly generated
    void constructInfile (fstream& aFile, char fileName[]);


    // Read data from infile txt file and transfer to array of numbers
    int constructArray (fstream& aFile,const char fileName[], Number ran[]);

    /*
    void processArray (Number [ ], int);

    // Transfer information from array and store into output file called outfile txt with specific information format
    void arrayToOutfile (fstream&, char [ ], Number [ ], int);
    */


    const int MAX = 50;

    int main()
    {
    srand(time(NULL));
    fstream aFile;
    char fileName [MAX];

    cout << "Enter designated file name to be created" << endl;
    cin >> fileName;

    constructInfile (aFile,fileName);

    Number ran[MAX];
    int recNo = constructArray(aFile,fileName,ran);
    cout << recNo << " of records transferred" << endl;

    }

    // Create inFile data file with certain number of integers which are randomly generated
    void constructInfile (fstream& aFile,char fileName[]){
        aFile.open(fileName, ios::out);

        if(aFile.fail()){
            cout << "File open unsuccessful" << endl;
            aFile.close();
            exit(1);
        }

        cout << "Begin creation of " << fileName << " file" << endl << endl;

        int size = rand()%51+50;

        for(int a = 0;a < size;a++){
            aFile << rand()%1000+1 << endl;
        }

        cout << fileName << " file successfully created" << endl;

    }


    // Read data from infile txt file and transfer to array of numbers
    int constructArray (fstream& aFile,const char fileName[], Number ran[]){

    aFile.open (fileName, ios::in);

        if (!aFile)
        {
            cout << fileName << " failed to open" << endl;
            aFile.close ();

            return 0;
        }

        cout << "Begin from " << fileName << " to array" << endl;

        int i = 0;

        char tabKey;

        while (aFile >> ran[i].no)
        {
            aFile.get (tabKey);     // read and discard
            i++;
        }

        aFile.close ();
        cout << fileName << " to array done" << endl;

        return i;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are opened a file in ios::out mode and never closed it!

Again you are trying to open the same file in ios::in mode. How a file could be opened twice in 2 different mode without properly closing the fstream?

You need to close the filestream inside the function `constructInfile()`!!!

Answer (score -1):

You have opened the file but forget to close it. At the end of both of the functions, close the `aFile`. That should solve the problem.

Comment: If the solution do not solve the problem, please check if the file is created or not and post the error message here.

Comment: Only second function is unable to work.
I've tried adding cerr << "Error: " << strerror(errno); under !aFile if statement
but it shows no error.

Comment: @MATU yes the second function is not able to open the file as it is already opened by the first function. so it needs to be closed at the end of the first function. And the general rules is to close the file after operations. That is why you also need to close the file in second function (best practice).